# What should be value of _singleton variable in deployProxy method?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

I want to know that sometimes people using Safe contract as singleton address where as sometimes people are using safeL2 contract as singleton address. So as per gnosis team which one should be preffered / more efficient ?

I am talking about scenario when user calling deployProxy method of SafeProxyFactory contract.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The regular singleton doesn't emit events for gas savings reasons and requires a tracing node for indexing. The L2 version emits events that can be used for indexing.